# EJB Server Detection

Tags: jboss, version

I would like to detect what server my EJB is running in, particularly between jBoss 6 and Glassfish 3.  I have been trying to get the EJBContext from inside an EJB in jBoss without success ("env not bound").

Is there any way at all to get the server name and version, or any other information, from inside an EJB in jBoss 6?

I have been able to get this information from inside a servlet using the servlet context, but I need it inside an EJB.

Thanks